Solving the optimal strategy of a Wordle game with stochastic optimization, where the distribution of answers is not uniform
I want to derive the optimal strategy of a Wordle game, where the distribution of answers is not uniform.
(This is inspired by the fact that some Wordle websites sample their answers according to the word frequency distribution; more frequently-used words are more likely to be the answer)
Here's my formulation:
Let $\mathcal W$ be the set of all valid words (of length $L$), and $\mathbb P$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal W$. Let $\mathcal F=2^{\mathcal W}$. Then $(\mathcal W,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space. Let $w_t$ be the answer taken from $\mathcal W$, which is a random variable with probabiliity distribution $\mathbb P$.
The filtration $\mathcal F_i$ is defined by
$$
\mathcal F_i=\sigma(\{\mathcal C(g_k,w_t)\}_{k\leq i})
$$
where $\mathcal C:\mathcal W\times\mathcal W\to \mathcal O$ is the coloring function (given by conventional Wordle coloring rules), $g_k\in\mathcal W$ is the $k$-th guess, $\mathcal O$ is the set of all ternary sequences of length $L$.
Define
$$
\mathbb P_i(\cdot)=\mathbb P(\cdot\mathop | \mathcal F_i),
$$
we have the recursion formula
$$
\mathbb P_{i+1}(\cdot)=\mathbb P_i(\cdot\mathop | \mathcal C(g_i,w_t))=\frac{\mathbb P_i(\cdot)\mathbb 1[\mathcal C(g_i,w_t)=\mathcal C(g_i,\cdot)]}{\sum_{w'\in \mathcal W}\mathbb P_i(w')\mathbb 1[\mathcal C(g_i,w_t)=\mathcal C(g_i,w')]}.
$$
Let $\tau$ be the stopping time defined by
$$
\tau=\inf\{i\in\mathbb N^+:g_i=w_t\},
$$
which is the number of steps to finish the puzzle. We minimize a convex function of $\tau$:
$$
\min\ \mathbb E[c(\tau)]
$$
choosing values of $g_i$. Without loss of generality, we can set $c(0)=0$.

However, I have no idea how to continue. I can't find in my stochastic optimization reference books how to solve this kind of problem (I thought it is an optimal stopping problem at first, but in this case the stopping rule is fixed). Can someone give me some ideas? (You can solve the simpler case of minimizing $\mathbb E[\tau]$ first.)

Here's my attempt at solving it with DP.
Let
$$
\beta_i=c(i)-c(i-1).
$$
Choose $c(\cdot)$ such that $c(0)=0$ and all $\beta_i\leq 1$.
Define the value function:
$$
V(i,\mathbb P_i)=\min_{\{g_k\in\mathcal W\}_{k\geq i}} \mathbb E\left(\sum_{k=i}^{\infty}\beta_k\mathbb 1[k\leq\tau]\mathop {\Bigg |} \mathcal F_i\right)=\min_{\{g_k\in\mathcal W\}_{k\geq i}}\int_{\mathcal W}\sum_{k=i}^{\infty}\beta_k\mathbb 1[k\leq\tau]\,\mathrm d {\mathbb P_i}.
$$
The Bellman equation is (not sure if this is correct—can a probability measure be the state variable?)
$$
V(i,\mathbb P_i)=\min_{g_i\in\mathcal W}[\beta_i+V(i+1,\mathbb P_{i+1})
]
$$
where
$$
\mathbb P_{i+1}(\cdot)=\mathbb P_i(\cdot\mathop | \mathcal C(g_i,w_t))=\frac{\mathbb P_i(\cdot)\mathbb 1[\mathcal C(g_i,w_t)=\mathcal C(g_i,\cdot)]}{\sum_{w'\in \mathcal W}\mathbb P_i(w')\mathbb 1[\mathcal C(g_i,w_t)=\mathcal C(g_i,w')]}.
$$
The boundary condition is
$$
V(i,\mathbb P_i)=\beta_i,
$$
if $\mathbb P_i(w_t)=1$ for some $w_t\in\mathcal W$.

I normally wouldn't bother to answer, as I've got no experience with stochastic optimization, but since you've asked for even the most minimal ideas ....
My understanding is that the "standard" wordle guess selection algorithm is:
Keep a list of possible answers and to treat each possible guess as partitioning that list into groups of words that "score the same", i.e. would produce the same tile set if they were the answer.
To each such partition we associate the (information theoretical) entropy. So you calculate the partition entropy produced by each possible guess, and go with the guess that maximizes that entropy.
With this strategy it's very easy to incorporate a non-uniform answer distribution: when computing the entropy of a list partition (where $\{L_i\}_{i=1}^{3^5}$ is a partition of the current list $L$), instead of calculating the probabilities as
$$p(L_i) = \frac{\#(L_i)}{\#(L)}$$
you use
$$p(L_i) = \frac{\sum_{w \in L_i}f(w)}{\sum_{w \in L}f(w)}$$
where $w$ are the words in the lists and $f(w)$ is the frequency of the word $w$ (which I guess I've assumed you have access to).
I couldn't see how to slot this into the paradigm you're working in, but t.b.h. I didn't go very deep into it. But maybe you can see a way to use it? Good luck.

Thank you for your answer!

@SteveNorkus - Thanks for awarding the bounty - sorry I couldn't give you more appropriate suggestions. Good luck working on this - sounds like it could be fun.

I found this article called "An Exact and Interpretable Solution to Wordle" by Bertsimas & Paskov: https://auction-upload-files.s3.amazonaws.com/Wordle_Paper_Final.pdf. In their paper, they formulated it as a MDP problem and solved it with a machine learning algorithm.
